# Excel Conditional Formatting for Multiple Entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am having trouble applying a formula to multiple cells on excel using conditional formatting. This is my formula: `=OR($E$3>$H$3,$E$3<$H$3)`
It only does it for one cell, I am trying to do it for the entire column, is there any way to do this. 
My end goal is something like this:

```
=OR($E$3>$H$3,$E$3<$H$3)
=OR($E$4>$H$4,$E$4<$H$4)
=OR($E$5>$H$5,$E$5<$H$5)
```

and so on and so forth. About 500 cells. I don't want to write it all out like that. Any way to just write it once. Thank you

Comment: Just apply the formatting to `E3` (select only E3 then add conditional formatting rule with just the first formula above) then paste formats down all 500 rows

Comment: or highlight all 500 rows and enter the formula. it will apply to the whole range. (keeping $ signs where ensure each row of cells has formula applied).

Comment: I tried that. I feel like I am missing a step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it will be unwise to contradict my learned colleagues but IMHO you need to get rid of the dollar signs

```
=OR(E3>H3,E3<H3)
```

But saying E3 is greater than H3 or E3 is less than H3 is the same as saying E3 is not equal to H3 so your formula will just boil down to

```
=E3<>H3
```

If you apply this to a whole range starting at E3, conditional formatting will automatically use relative addressing so in effect you get

```
=E4<>H4
```

in the next row and so on.

You only need to use a dollar sign if you are pulling it across more than one column and need to anchor it to particular columns, so in this case the formula would be

```
=$E3<>$H3
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I apply formula to differet sheets rather than rewriting the entire thing again

Comment: So I used that formula: `=$E3<>$H3` and I applied it to `=$H$3:$J$498`. The method only works when all three columns (H,I,J) are not equal to (E,F,G). Any way to do it so the formula would work for just one column to have a different value

Comment: The answer to the first question is that you should be able to use the Format Painter (paintbrush symbol) to copy the formats across onto another sheet.

Comment: If you use =$E3<>$H3 what will happen is that it will only compare columns E & H - the dollar sign locks it to those columns. If you leave out the dollar signs and try it again it will use relative addressing on columns so it will get modified to =F3<>I3 and =G3<>J3 - this will do a separate compare on pairs of columns E&H, F&I and G&J. If you wanted to highlight _all_ columns if _any_ pair were different, you would be back to using an or formula like =or($E3<>$H3,$F3<>$I3,$G3<>$J3). Tip: try entering the formulas directly into the sheet and check what happens as you pull down and across.